# What's happening with my process?

Tags: ruby, linux, kernel

The following process is still alive, but the actual code has finished. How do I go about making sure the process gets ended?

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START    TIME COMMAND
root      8100 90.4  3.4  13364  8956 ?        Rl   Jun07 2335:22 ruby haccts.rb
```

I found out what `R` and `l` stand for:

```
R    Running or runnable (on run queue)
l    Multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthread do)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about Ruby, but in most programming languages, you add `return 0;` at the end of the program. I think it was something like `Process.Exit()` in Ruby however.

Comment: Tell me how my reputation changes for editing. And if you say nothing changed, tell me what "you add return 0; add the end of the program" means. I thought that is not a grammatical sentence. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Didn't you get 2 points reputation for editing? And I didn't see any mistakes in the sentence >.< Ok sorry I didn't say anything xD